# An alternative to global variables in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: caching, configuration, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-1.1

In an ASP.Net Core 1.1 Web API, I need to store some global information that must be accessible across all controllers. So when the client calls a certain endpoint on the API, a certain variable (a Dictionary) must be set, which will be read from all other controllers. From what I've seen, it's apparently a bad idea to use global static variables? Could maybe someone tell me why, and what is a better alternative? I've heard about using configuration files or cache...

Comment: I've edited your title to make the question a bit less subjective and removed the "Any recommendations?" at the end of the body of the question as stackoverflow is not a site for recommendations and asking for recommendations often results in the question being closed and unanswerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A major reason that many developers don't like to use global variables is that they can make it difficult (or impossible) to fully unit test a class that uses them. Developers that unit test their code tend to prefer dependency injection over global variables.

If the needed variables are "injected into the class" by passing them into the class via the class's constructor parameters, then unit testes can pass in known values for these variables which makes the desired outcomes for the test predictable. This aids unit testing dramatically. You can learn more about ASP.NET Core dependency injection from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection).

Another issue with global variables is that they can be changed from anywhere. So when debugging it can sometimes be challenging to track down which piece of code changed them. By using dependency injection rather than global variables, the developer knows the specific classes that have access to the variable.

Comment: Yes this is definitely a scenario best answered by DI, and either an InMemory implementation based on an AddSingleton or a distributed based on IDistributedCache (which is probably a better option since in the modern web world you often have several servers).